# IIS7 Conditional Redirect

Tags: iis-7

I am trying to use IIS7 URL Rewrite to:

1)  Individual home page:
subdomain.domain.com

Redirect to

individual home page:
domain.com/subdomain

AND

2)  subdomain.domain.com/?URL=http://subdomain.domain.com/site/preview/xxxx

Redirect to

subdomain.domain.com/site/preview/xxxx

Where xxxx is a 4-digit article number that changes based on the article opened.

unfortunately, while we were able to make the first rule work, the second one didn't, as it redirects to the same location as the first one

Any assistance on this matter would be much appreciated.

Thank you.